# [UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing a editable table view in project. When I tap the red `Delete` button shows after left swiping, App just crashed. Console log is here:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716`

In my table view, there are many sections, but each with only one row because I need the section header to separate each cell. Here are my implementation of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
#pragma mark - Delegate Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.dataSource.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15.f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.01f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyNewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellReuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell setCellWithModel:self.dataSource[indexPath.section]];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought. If you have only one row in each section maybe consider integrating section "view" as a part of table cell, you'll end up with much simpler table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` 
is still returning 1 after you have delete the row.

You have to delete the section

`[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]`